# Unable to Encrypt the xml soap message using gsoap-2.8.116

Tags: gsoap

One of my project has the need to encrypt the soap message using X509 certificate and send the encrypted message to the server. Below code was working fine in the older version of gsoap but when I upgraded it to latest 2.8.116 it is encrypting the soap header but not the SOAP:Body part and that is causing the problem.

'''

int main() {
soap_wsse_set_wsu_id(( * proxy) -> soap, "wsse:BinarySecurityToken SOAP-ENV:Body");

```
if (soap_wsse_add_BinarySecurityTokenX509(( * proxy) -> soap, "X509Token", * cert1) ||
    soap_wsse_add_KeyInfo_SecurityTokenReferenceX509(( * proxy) -> soap, "#X509Token") ||
    soap_wsse_sign_body(( * proxy) -> soap, SOAP_SMD_SIGN_RSA_SHA256, * pkey1, 0) ||
    soap_wsse_sign_only(( * proxy) -> soap, "SOAP-ENV:Body")) {
    return (3);
}

char * token1, * token2;
if (cfg.isEncryptionEnabled) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sk_X509_num( * ca); i++) {
        char subj[1024];
        X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(sk_X509_value( * ca, i)), subj, sizeof(subj));
        for (token1 = strtok_r(subj, "=", & token2); token1; token1 = strtok_r(NULL, "=", & token2)) {
            if (strcmp(SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY_NAME, token1) == 0) {
                if (soap_wsse_add_EncryptedKey(( * proxy) -> soap, SOAP_MEC_AES256_CBC, "Cert", sk_X509_value( * ca, i), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
                    return (4);
                }`enter code here`
            }
        }
    }
}

int check = soap_write_ns2__RequestMessage(proxy -> soap, ns2__requestMessage);
proxy -> soap -> os = NULL;
proxy -> soap_endpoint = cfg.serverURL;

int status = runTransaction(ns2__requestMessage, ** ns2__replyMessage);
```

}
'''

great if someone can help here.

Comment: Which older version of gsoap are you referring to?

Comment: It could be that if `soap_wsse_add_EncryptedKey` is not called at all and nothing gets encrypted. Are you sure the logic prevents this from happening to ensure that `soap_wsse_add_EncryptedKey` is actually called? There does not seem to be any check to prevent unencrypted messaging if the loop and strcmp fail.

Comment: Alex, I am using gsoap 2.8.116 which is latest one.

Comment: I checked, soap_wsse_add_EncryptedKey() is always getting called.  what I understand is soap_wsse_add_EncryptedKey() encrypt the header and initiate the context for body encryption. I debug more and found that fun soap_wsse_add_EncryptedKey stores the reference function for the soap->feltbegout. This reference is usefull to encrypt the body. when soap_write_ns2__RequestMessage() is getting called that reference started pointing to null. so the next call runTransaction() just ignore the body encryption.